# Jquery var to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I print this json in the same php page I call this ajax? 
It is returning a mysql select and is printing in console but I dont know how to print in php

```
$('.itemview').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uid = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/controllers/get.php",
        data: 'id='+uid,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log(data.result);
                console.log(data.result.id);
                $("#MethodView").modal('show');
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I got this in console:

```
Object
bank_info:null
entry_day:"0"
entry_type:"now"
form_of_payment:"y"
form_of_receipt:"y"
id:"1"
installment:"n"
name:"Dinheiro"
tax:"n"
type:"immediate"
```

And i need to print this in the same page I call this ajax

Answer (score 0):

If by php, you mean how to show data on modal then you can do the following:

```
$("#MethodView").append('<div id="modal_data"></div>');
$('#modal_data').html(''your response');
$("#MethodView").modal('show');
```

Comment: I want to print success: function (data) in the same page I call this ajax